# mysql query no longer works

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make it so that you can upload a ppt and it will split into a pdf for each slide. i have already made a shell script to do the ppt splitting and that works, however i am having trouble with my sql query to update my database. I had it working at one point and then all of a sudden it stopped working, not sure what i did to mess it up but it looks fine to me. Here is some of the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])){

$admin_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$name = $_POST['title'];

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    $fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $dir = "powerpoints/".$name;
    $ispdf = "1";
    echo $tmp_name."----------------".$dir;

    echo $admin_id.':'.$name.':'.$dir.':'.$ispdf;

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO problem (admin_id,topic,image,is_pdf) VALUES ('$admin_id','$name','$dir','$ispdf')");
    //$output = shell_exec('mkdir '.$dir);
    //echo $output;
    if($query && move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir.$fname)){
        //$cmd = 'importppt.sh '.str_replace(".pdf", "", $name);
        $message = "Powerpoint uploaded";
    }elseif($query){
        $message = "move_uploaded_file() Failed";
    }else{
        $message = "Database Error";
    }`
```

when i try to use the script Database Error is printed which means it skipped over "elseif($query)" 
also note that there are more columns in my database that i am not updating, however it should just leave them blank for the new entry like it has before it stopped working. all of the names are spelled correctly and the data being put into the query is printed correctly by my echo statement

Comment: You should echo `mysql_error()` - that'll tell you what's going on. Side note: don't use `mysql_*()` for new code: it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: the first thing I saw wrong is that you're not sanitizing your inputs, so if `$name` has `'` in it, your query will break. as mentioned by the comment above use this: `mysql_query("INSERT...") or die(mysql_error());` so that you know what's exactly happening.

Comment: Yea i have to make the change to mysqli sometime, i just havent had a chance to do it yet. thanks for the echo mysql_error() tip tho, it comes back as Duplicate entry '' for key 'problem'. im assuming that it means the column problem not the name of the table problem, however the only key is the id column and that auto increments

Comment: seems like your `problem` column is set to unique.

Comment: changing the query so that it updates column "problem" solves the problem until i try the query again with the same "Key" used before

Comment: @codebird that is definitely it. idk how that happened. is there a way to make it not unique without deleting the column? i dont want to mess up my data. im using phpmyadmin

Comment: `ALTER TABLE problem DROP INDEX problem` in phpmyadmin you can click show indexes under the table structure then drop the index

Comment: I wasnt sure if that would delete the column or not but that worked. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Query For testing

```
error_reporting(-1) ;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO problem (admin_id,topic,image,is_pdf) VALUES 
('admin_id','name','dir','ispdf')");

$temp = false;
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir.$fname)){
    $temp = true;
}

if($query && $temp){
    $message = "Powerpoint uploaded,";
}
else if($query){
    $message = "Problem Find In your TITLE, Or Duplicate Data, OR Use mySqli";
}else if(!$temp){
      $message = "Problem Find In your mov directory, Check manually";
}
else{
        $message = "Hope This Else Will not work";
}
```

Comment: if you read the comments of my post you can see i figured out the mysql error, just dont know how to fix it

Comment: Couldnt scroll up and read it?! Duplicate entry '' for key 'problem'. i have discovered that my "problem" is set to unique and im trying to figure out how to remove this property without ruining my data that is already there.